# Crashed site/site is down

Tags: google-cloud-platform

guys!
I am running a site on GCP AND USING THE THEME COLORMAG. I was updating the theme and then the site crashed. I can log in to the backend but everything is wiped away.
The error I am getting is that the theme directory is not there.
What do I do?

Answer (score -1):

You can change back the theme in the database, there are really good guides that you can use: https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/wordpress/change-theme-in-db/
https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-properly-change-a-wordpress-theme/

Also if you have a WP backup you can use that and try to install/use the theme again.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.